# tr -c '[a-zA-Z]' '\n' not replacing all complement characters

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, tr

Writting a script I wanted to replace all characters except alpha ([a-zA-Z]) with a line break. By definition, when using -c flag (set complement) tr is supposed to replace all characters that are not in the SET1 with the character specified in SET2. Nevertheless, it doesn't work as expected...
Try this:

```
echo '[[:lower:]]' | tr -c '[a-zA-Z]' '\n'
```

Output I get:

```
[[
lower
]]
```

As it can be seen it replaces columns but not square brackets, which it it is supposed to replace.

Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tr` doesn't intepret character classes in that regex style.

`[a-zA-Z]` is interpreted as a set of `[`, the range of characters from `a` to `z` and `]`.

Therefore its complement is the set of characters including all the characters but `[`, the range of characters from `a` to `z` and `]`.

That's why `[` and `]` aren't replaced.

To replace any non-alphabetic character, just specify `a-zA-Z` as the complement of the set to be replaced:

```
echo '[[:lower:]]' | tr -c 'a-zA-Z' '\n'
```

```
% echo '[[:lower:]]' | tr -c 'a-zA-Z' '\n'



lower



%
```

Comment: incosistency everywhere :3 Thanks mate!